# Why does the linux nohup command return "Alarm clock" after 12 hours of running and prematurely terminate the operation?

Tags: linux, timeout, nohup

I have a very long running Linux command that converts the contents of one large file and creates a new large file. After running for 12 hours it stops processing and returns some nonsense about "Alarm clock" when I hit the enter key in the terminal session that launched the nohup. Here is what I'm seeing:

```
$ nohup cthookclient -m dot5-test -H ctrp04-dt54.bd.comp.net upldb >> upldb.out &
[1] 4198
nohup: ignoring input and redirecting stderr to stdout
[russp@repp02 data]$
[1]+  Alarm clock             nohup cthookclient -m dot5-test -H ctrp04-dt54.bd.comp.net upldb >> upldb.out
```

This process has worked correctly before, running to competition. Is the **nohup** command experiencing a timeout? I thought that was the whole point of using nohup so it won't timeout. I'm very lost on  this one.

Comment: Did  you search to see if your local environment has added some nagware `Alarm clock` ? `ps -ef | grep '[A]larm'` might help. Did you also confirm that the job has actually stopped `ps -ef | grep '[c]thookclient'` ? And what is happening with `>> upldb.out` `(tail -f upldb.out` in another window).  And why `>>` ? Create a new file every day. Confirm you still have diskspace for writing a file from a process that takes 12 hrs? Good luck!

Comment: Missed this earlier : *"and creates a new large file"* . Recall that `>>` is an append operator, so your `upldb.out` is getting bigger every time you run this. Is that what you want? If that is just logging information, best to research available logging utilities or at least use `> /path/to/log/dir/myLog.$(date +%Y-%m-%d.%H:%M)` . Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

`nohup` takes the output of the script and looks for something to print it out to.   So if it isn't writing to anything .. The forked `nohup` itself is most likely the thing getting quashed by the Alarm Clock, not your script.

Something like (or variation of) the following:

```
echo 1; nohup cthookclient -m dot5-test -H ctrp04-dt54.bd.comp.net upldb >& /dev/null
```

Is the idea .. Of course I cannot test it, but the concept is writing nohup out to something, even `dev/null` ..

Comment: Good stuff, but why eliminate any output that might help debug the problem? `echo 1; nohup ....  >> upldb.out 2> /tmp/problemJobNoHupOutput.txt  &` would be my attempt (who knows?).  Good luck to all!

Comment: Great suggestion - I was more focused on the X, I forgot about the Y!

Comment: LOL, yep! .. See my revised version. Ideally the process should capture the output with ` >> upldb.out`. Just send the errors to a file. Good luck to all.